# No styles or images in initial Symfony2 installation?

Tags: php, image, symfony, styles

I've been playing with Symfony for a bit but for some reason now, whenever I setup a new project the default styles and images are no longer being loaded. What is going on?

Followed the installation steps precisely as per the [instructions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html). I used the composer.phar method and have set permissions correctly.

Here is a screenshot of my unstyled demo page:

[image]

Comment: Have you clear the cache? app/console cache:clear

Comment: @m4t1t0 - Hi there, yep I've tried clearing the cache.

Answer (score 12):

If you followed the instrunctions 1 by 1, your assets are not installed...

you can do this, by a `php composer.phar update` when you added the mentioned extras to the composer.json

```
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "symlink"
}
```

or manually by

```
php app/console assets:install web
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by running

```
php app/console assets:install web
php app/console cache:clear
```

and lastly, re run your app

```
 php app/console server:run
```

Comment: i wonder why the quick tour on their homepage does not mention this